# is it safe to use CURL in multi threaded program, How can I make it thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, curl

I planned to use CURL to communicate with server. And this communication will take place as a separate thread.

I have a curl wrapper class as given below.

If I use the object of this wrapper class to communicate with different server in different thread or in the same thread would it be thread safe?

The following description from [curl website](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_global_init.html) confuse me.

> This function is not thread safe. You must not call it when any other thread in the program (i.e. a thread sharing the same memory) is running. This doesn't just mean no other thread that is using libcurl. Because curl_global_init calls functions of other libraries that are similarly thread unsafe, it could conflict with any other thread that uses these other libraries.

```
class curlWrapper
 { 
private:
    CURLcode curlCode;
    CURL *curlHandle;
    struct curl_slist *header = NULL;
    MemoryStruct response;

public:
    curlWrapper(){        
        curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);      

    }        
    ~curlWrapper(){
        curl_global_cleanup();            
    }

    CURL* curlInit();// curl_easy_init()
    CURLcode curlClose();// curl_easy_cleanUp()

    void initializeConnection();
    void sendRequest(const char* request);
    char* getResponse();
    void setMemorytoWrite();
    void listen();
    void closeConnection();
    void setURL(const char* url);
    void setHttpHeader(const char * contentType, const char * charSet);
    void setTrace(bool trace);// If true trace will be displayd
    void curlExec();

};`
```

could anyone please clarify the confusion?

Language: c++
Operating system: 
  In development : OS X.

In client side : This code will be installed in client machine which means they may use any OS.

Thanks

Comment: curl_global_init  is not thread safe, and should only be called once, right after `int main{  ` is a good location

Comment: Hi hanshenrik, Thanks for the reply. in such case my constructor and destructor should call curl_easy_init and clean up?.

Comment: right you are :) and just make sure not to have 2 threads doing an operation on the same curl handle simultaneously, and the easy_ functions are all thread safe. 1 possible way to stay safe, is to not share curl handles between threads

Comment: No I cant call curl_global_init in my main with my design. Because as per my design. Main only call the interface ( some classes which implement this interface using different way to connect with server like curl, gsoap, ...) . Whether the application going to use this or other will be decided at run time. I can’t really call this global init right after int main(){

Comment: fine, have a global std::atomic_bool where false is "not initialized", and true is "initialized", wherin, if its false, you have an exclusive mutex to initialize it, and when you aquire the mutex, you check again if its not true, then you start initialization, and when its done, you set it to true and release the mutex, and do whatever you were supposed to do

Comment: If I understand correctly, I should have `global_lock = false;` If I have multiple instances of this wrapper class, while calling the constructor of this class i should check `global_lock `  if it is false I should call global_int() and make this to true. which avoid further calling of global_init() from other thread, other object. But..

Comment: for the global_easy_cleanUp() how can I make sure that this method called only once that too after closing all the other easy_cleanup()s from other threads and objects. ?

Comment: maybe have the same code that does the global_init call atexit(curl_global_cleanup); ? although its rarely required, as the operating system does an excellent job of cleaning up at exit anyway. i'd imagine the only reason you'd want to call curl_global_cleanup before the program exits, is if your program is memory/handle constrained...

Comment: No, I just wanted to preserve the encapsulation of this class. If do atexit() i would break the encapsulation (I guess I am not wrong).  What about this? one global counter which increment whenever i call global easy_init() and decrement whenever I call easy_cleanup(). if it turned to 0 I will make sure there is no other curl processing and it is a safe time to call global_cleanup(). Is there any potential misunderstandings or drawbacks? (I am new for C++ and curl )